# How to simplify and display an equation using C?

Tags: c, programming-languages, polynomial-math

I want to find the characteristic equation of a matrix . I`m aware of how it is done mathematically but how do I display it in the form of an equation ?
eg :
Given matrix :

```
3 7 9
8 6 2
1 8 6
```

now if suppose the parameter is , say "b";
my next step is to do this ;

```
3-b 7   9
8   6-b 2
1   8   6-b
```

till here I can only display by doing this :

```
printf("%d - %c ", a[i][j],98);
```

but then how do I find this determinant of matrix from here ??
my final  equation should be of form like

```
b^3 + 3b^2 - 4b +5 =0
```

and all of this simplification should be done in the program.
Can this be done in C ? If not , is there any other way  or language that makes this simplification possible ? I don`t want to  just display a character , I want it to be involved in the calculation and remain intact in the final answer. Thanks .

Comment: Since C is a turing-complete language, is equivalent to do it on any other turing-complete language.

Comment: Do you want [symbolic computation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_computation) in C?

Comment: symbolic computaion does fit the description but can it be implemented using C ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like [symbolic computation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_computation). It's easily implemented in MATLAB if you have the [Symbolic Math toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/symbolic/) or in [GNU Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) (as described in this [tutorial](http://faraday.elec.uow.edu.au/subjects/annual/ECTE313/Symbolic_Maths.pdf)) which is freely available.

Google recommends [GiNaC](http://www.ginac.de/tutorial/) for C++. Further googling may turn up something for C.

Comment: @user553492: then, if the answer is useful to you, upvote it!

Comment: You don't need symbolic computation to find the coefficiencts of the characteristic polynome of a matrix.

Comment: @etarion: I think the OP knows how to evaluate it himself ("all of this simplification should be done in the program").

Comment: It isn't about "evaluating it himself", it's about not needing symbolic computation to do this algorithmically. It's basically a one-liner if you have a linear algebra package, see http://codepad.org/eHfkkDz6 for a python example (can't be bugged to implement this in C in the middle of the night)